# jupyter/ipython matplotlib ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, conda

I installed graphviz with conda and then when using jupyter notebook, I got the following error when importing matplotlib

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application for Python Matplotlib
```

So, I deinstalled graphviz and matplotlib, reinstalled matplotlib and now I get

```
matplotlib ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import matplotlib
>>>
```

This is my anaconda environment

```
platform : win-64
conda version : 4.1.11
conda-env version : 2.5.2
conda-build version : 1.21.3
python version : 2.7.11.final.0
requests version : 2.9.1
root environment : C:\Anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : C:\Anaconda3
envs directories : C:\Anaconda3\envs
package cache : C:\Anaconda3\pkgs
channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64/
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch/
config file : None
offline mode : False
is foreign system : False
```

Is there anything I should try before I go and axe my whole conda and jupyter installs? I would prefer to avoid that.